# css - how to change grid layout without using media query

Tags: css-grid, grid-layout

I'm creating a header for a site, which has several individual items. I'm using css grid and want to avoid using media query for changing the layout when contents don't fit. Having trouble getting the grid setup.

My html structure looks like this:

```html
<header class="container">
  <div id="brand">...</div>
  <div id="hamburger-menu>...</div>
  <nav id="nav1">...</nav>
  <nav id="nav2">...</nav>
</header>
```

Below is my current css code:

```css
#brand { grid-area: brand; }
#hamburger-icon { grid-area: hamburgerIcon; }
#nav1 { grid-area: nav1; }
#nav2 { grid-area: siteNav; }

.container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 450px auto ;
   grid-template-rows: auto;
   grid-row-gap: 16px;
   grid-template-areas:
     "brand nav1"
     "brand nav2";
}
```

The above CSS gives me a layout that looks like this:

```
| brand | nav1 |
|       | ---- |
|       | nav2 |
```

This is fine on a larger screen. In my case `nav2` is expected to be much longer. So, in smaller screens (not mobile/tablet), the current layout overflows to the right side.

I'd like to have the `nav1` and `nav2` just flow "under" the brand, but only when necessary. For example, move `nav2` to the second row when it doesn't fit anymore.

```
| brand | nav1 |
| ----- | ---- |
|     nav2     |
```

I know I can probably set the media query and based on screen size change the `grid-template-areas` but I'm wondering if that's the only way.

This article is really good that shows media query is not necessary, but I'm having trouble applying it in my case.

https://css-tricks.com/look-ma-no-media-queries-responsive-layouts-using-css-grid/

Any suggestions?